# Images on android/alloy project

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-alloy

My view:

```
 <Alloy>
        <Window class="container">
            <View id="top_view">
                <ImageView id="logo" />
                <ImageView id="title" />
            </View>
        </Window>
    </Alloy>
```

My tss:

```
 "#logo": {
        width: "42",
        height: "63",
        image: "/images/logo.png"
    },
    "#title": {
        width: "172",
        height: "35",
        image: "/images/title.png"
    }
```

Using this code my images are not displayed. Images are in good folders, because when they weren't I got this error: `TiDrawableReference: (pool-3-thread-2) [1288,1288] Could not open stream to get bitmap`

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project in Alloy (3.2.3.GA on a Mac) and copied in the code above and it displayed the jpg images on the iPad simulator.  I added

```
".container": {
    backgroundColor:"white"
},
```

to the .tss file but it will still work without that.  However when I changed the filename to a nonexistent file it didn't give any error.  When I changed the folder to a nonexistent folder it also didn't give an error.  So I would double check and make sure your files are where they are supposed to be.  Remember in Alloy the images are automatically copied to the Resources folder on build so if you put the files there they will be deleted.  According to your .tss file your images should be in the assets folder here:

`<project folder>/app/assets/images/logo.png`